# Add new line in jLabel when displaying data from file

Tags: java, swing

I am displaying the contents of a file in a `jLabel`. I want to add new line after every line read from a file, this is the `jLabel.setText()` code,

```
LeftSideDisplay.setText(LeftSideDisplay.getText() + entry.getKey() + entry.getValue().toString() //add new line here);
```

I tried doing,

```
LeftSideDisplay.setText(LeftSideDisplay.getText() + entry.getKey() + entry.getValue().toString() + "<html><br/></html>");
```

still no help.

Comment: LeftSideDisplay.setText(LeftSideDisplay.getText() + "<html><br /></html>"+ entry.getKey() + entry.getValue().toString());
Is this the thing you are trying?

Comment: I tried every combination. Nothing worked, sometimes data won't even show. Sometimes, just single line read is shown. @RajuDangol

Comment: Try this
LeftSideDisplay.setText( "<html>"+LeftSideDisplay.getText() + "<br />"+ entry.getKey() + entry.getValue().toString()+"</html>");

Comment: You need to wrap ALL the text in HTML, not just the `br`.  A better solution would be to use a non-editable `JTextArea`

Comment: @RajuDangol, that would only add a newline before first entry, wouldn't it? Wouldn't make a difference I guess.

Comment: JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>");
label.settext(label.getText+"<br />"+entry.getValue().toString());

Comment: I used `jTextPane` as I wanted to center-align the text and it worked fine, thanks for your help @MadProgrammer.

Comment: @RajuDangol, please try to include your code in back-ticks. It is easier to read that way.